# subquery in LINQ for Update

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I make a subquery in LINQ?
Query looks

```
UPDATE bikes SET name = @name, bike_type_id = @type, bike_type = (SELECT name FROM(SELECT name FROM type_bike WHERE id = @type) as tmp) WHERE id = @id
```

I'm trying to do

```
var obj = this.context.bikes.Single(x => x.id == id);
obj.name = name;
obj.bike_type = this.context.type_bike.Where(x=> x.id == typeBike).Select(q=> q.name).ToString();
obj.bike_type_id = typeBike;          
this.context.SubmitChanges();
```

But it does not work

Comment: .Select(q=> q.name).FirstOrDefault().ToString();

Comment: "Does not work" is not an adequate problem description. Post any error messages you received, or what you expected to happen vs. what actually did happen.

Comment: @AshokDamani `ToString` is redundant if `name` is a string. Also, if `FirstOrDefault` is `null`, you'll get a nice `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var obj = this.context.bikes.SingleOrDefault(x => x.id == id);
// check if the obj is not null. 
if(obj!=null)
{
    obj.name = name;
    // I suppose that each bike has a unique type. Hence, I am not using the 
    // SingleOrDefault() and then checking if the result is null.
    obj.bike_type = this.context.type_bike
                        .Where(x=> x.id == id)
                        .Select(q=>q.name)
                        .Single();
    obj.bike_type_id = typeBike;          
    this.context.SubmitChanges(); 
}
```

I suppose that in your where clause in obj.bike_type assignment, you didn't use the proper id.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use relations to get names of records like bike type. In your case you should not use `ToString()` since it will return the sql statement. Instead you should use `FirstOrDefault()` or `SingleOrDefault()` which selects to first found name.